# Is it not possible to store UI-related variables in the Panel itself?

Tags: python, panel, custom-properties

I'm making a custom panel for a pet-project, very new to Python and Blender. One thing I noticed that in all example panels I can find, all input is stored in global objects, like scene object. I tried storing the object in the panel class instance, I can read it from within Python, but if I require user input, the panel item does not see the property, although I use "self" as the source object. Am I doing something wrong, and if not, doesn't this create namespace problems, scripts overwriting properties of each-other?

An example code:

```
    #this works
    layout.prop(context.scene, "theChosenObject")
    #this doesn't work
    layout.prop(self, "my_property")
```

Comment: Hello ! The answer is no, you can't store properties in panels, they're essentially UI-only constructs and not serialized.

Comment: @Gorgious Thanks! So it's somewhat harder to keep clutter things clutter free but I'm guessing the best practice is to make a single PropertyGroup with a unique name, and tuck everything inside of that.